# Using gen.coroutine’s callback argument in Tornado

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, tornado

Looking for a simple example demonstrating use of [`tornado.gen.coroutine`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/gen.html#tornado.gen.coroutine)’s `callback` argument. The docs say:

> Functions with [the `gen.coroutine`] decorator return a `Future`. Additionally, they may be called with a `callback` keyword argument, which will be invoked with the future’s result when it resolves.

Adapting [an example](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/coroutines.html#how-to-call-a-coroutine) from the docs’ User’s guide, I would think I could do:

```
from tornado import gen

@gen.coroutine
def divide(x, y):
    return x / y

@gen.coroutine
def good_call():
    yield divide(1, 2)

good_call(callback=print)
```

I’d expect this to print `0.5`, but there’s no output.

I’ve found copious examples demonstrating the deprecated [`gen.engine`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/gen.html#tornado.gen.engine) decorator, but there doesn’t seem to be as much out there on `gen.coroutine`. Running on Python 3.5.1 and Tornado 4.3.

Comment: is this python2? ... try `sys.stdout.write` instead of print (since print is a statement in py2)

Comment: For more examples, see [Refactoring Tornado Coroutines](https://emptysqua.re/blog/refactoring-tornado-coroutines/).

Comment: @A.JesseJiryuDavis Thanks. I'd read that article, but it doesn't contain examples using of the `callback` argument.

Comment: I'd recommend *not* trying to mix coroutines and callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

You still need to start the IOLoop. If you add `tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()` at the end of your script you'll see the output printed (and then the `IOLoop` runs forever. If you want it to stop, you'll need to do so from your callback after printing).

Note that in general it is possible (and encouraged) to write Tornado applications using only coroutines and `yield`, without passing any callbacks directly.

Comment: Thanks. I started the loop, but the output was `None`, not `0.5`. I tried debugging, but hit a wall with all the functools acrobatics. (I’ll try to avoid the `callback` argument, but still want to understand why this doesn’t work.)

Comment: It does not work as expected, because `good_call` must return something that will be passed to callback. Use `return (yield divide(1, 2))` in `good_call`.

Comment: I would interpret the line "The raw Future version is more complex, but Futures are nonetheless recommended practice in Tornado ..." (http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/async.html) to lead us to believe that Tornado wants us to write our applications using Futures (and adding callbacks to the Futures)... Am I misinterpreting this?

Comment: You're encouraged to use coroutines, which are built on Futures under the hood but which mostly hide the Futures and callbacks from the application.